# React JS How to make a Button create another Button

Tags: reactjs, button, addition

So I have an "Add" button that, once clicked, I want to open another button in which the user can add some text. The reason the second (newly opened) button is a button is because it will serve as a link to another page. If anyone cares to know, I'm trying to build an app where people can track certain exercises/movements. This first page will be where they write in the names of the movements they want to track.

Here is the code I have for the "Add" button:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AddCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddCircle';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    background: '#C4C4C4',
    fontFamily: 'PT Sans Caption',
    fontSize: '18px',
    borderRadius: '10px',
    padding: '20px',
    marginTop: '50px',
    width: '700px'
  },
}));

export default function AddMovementButton() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        className={classes.button}
        startIcon={<AddCircleIcon />}>
        Add Movement
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is the code for the button that I would like to appear after the "Add" is clicked:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    button: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        background: '#C4C4C4',
        fontFamily: 'PT Sans Caption',
        fontSize: '18px',
        borderRadius: '10px',
        padding: '20px',
        marginTop: '50px',
        width: '700px',
    },
    newMovement: {
        border: 'none',
        padding: '10px',
        fontFamily: 'PT Sans Caption',
        fontSize: '18px',
        borderRadius: '10px',

    }
}));

export default function MovementButton(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    //const [ exercise ] = useState(props.exercise)

    return (
        <Button
            variant="contained"
            className={classes.button}>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Movement Here" className={classes.newMovement}/>
        </Button>
    );
};
```

Here is a picture of what I have on my browser. The two buttons that say "Enter Movement Here" are there because I called them in the home page. The goal would be for the homepage to start with just the "Add Movement" button and then grow as the user adds movements.
[image]

If I left out any needed info just let me know, and also I'm fairly new to coding so any other tips/corrections would be appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: why are u using input type='text' inside the Button what is the purpose?

Comment: I want to allow the user to type in their own exercise movement and I figured the input type="text" would be the best way to let them do that. If you have a suggestion on how to do it differently/better I would love the help.

Comment: you add a button & input within a div element(don't use input type =' text' inside the button because if you add onClick event for button and you click the input the Onclick event always trigger)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a state to count the button click, use the for loop to generate the buttons.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AddCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddCircle';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    background: '#C4C4C4',
    fontFamily: 'PT Sans Caption',
    fontSize: '18px',
    borderRadius: '10px',
    padding: '20px',
    marginTop: '50px',
    width: '700px'
  },
}));

export default function AddMovementButton() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const generateButton s= () => {
    let buttons = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       buttons.push(<MovementButton />);
    }
    return buttons;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {generateButtons()}
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        className={classes.button}
        onClick={() => setCount(count => count + 1)}
        startIcon={<AddCircleIcon />}>
        Add Movement
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```